# Is a message queue for incoming/outgoing messages needed?

Tags: networking, tcp, queue

The state of affairs: A GUI program, implemented in Java or C#, communicates with a low-one-digit-range number of devices via TCP/IP. Connections are GUI<-->Device only, never Device<--->Device.

Network traffic tends to be low, but the devices tend to send their messages in a somewhat synchronized manner.

The GUI takes a message, reads it and updates a simple graphic representation of the data. Its CPU usage hovers around 5%.

Although we've yet to see any networking problems, we're thinking of adding send and recieve queues in the GUI program.

Is this ...

- entirely nonsensical?
- well-advised?
- urgently needed?

Comment: No. There already are queues, in the form of the socket send and receive buffers. Don't gild the lily.

Comment: @user207421 Could you make the comment into an answer, please?